# Java - Log4j2 programmatically add ErrorHandler

Tags: java, log4j2

I am working with Log4j2.
The requirement is that if the logger is not able to write to the logfile (access denied, locked, etc) the application should shut down.

I've written the following class to achieve this:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.ErrorHandler;

public class LogFileErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {
   private static final Logger LOGGER = StatusLogger.getLogger();

   @Override
   public void error(String msg) {
      LOGGER.error(msg);

      System.exit(ExitCodes.IO_LOGGER_COULD_NOT_WRITE);
   }

   ... more error implementations
}
```

I am building my FileLogger programmatically with the code here:

```
public static final ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> BUILDER = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder

public void initFileLoggerWithFilePattern(final String pattern) {
   final LoggerComponentBuilder   logger   = BUILDER.newLogger("FileLogger", Level.DEBUG);
   final AppenderComponentBuilder appender = createFileAppenderWithFilePattern(pattern);

   BUILDER.add(appender);

   logger.add(BUILDER.newAppenderRef("RollingFileAppender"));

   BUILDER.add(logger);

   Configurator.initialize(BUILDER.build());
}

public AppenderComponentBuilder createFileAppenderWithFilePattern(final String pattern) {
   final AppenderComponentBuilder acb = BUILDER.newAppender("RollingFileAppender", "RollingFile");
   acb.addAttribute("fileName",    pattern); 
   acb.addAttribute("filePattern", pattern);
   acb.addComponent(createPatternLayout());
   acb.addComponent(createTimeBasedTriggeringPolicy());

   return acb;
}

public LayoutComponentBuilder createPatternLayout() {
   final LayoutComponentBuilder lcb = BUILDER.newLayout("PatternLayout");
   lcb.addAttribute("pattern", "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}{GMT}Z %m");

   return lcb;
}

public ComponentBuilder createTimeBasedTriggeringPolicy() {
   final ComponentBuilder policies = BUILDER.newComponent("Policies");
   final ComponentBuilder policy   = BUILDER.newComponent("TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy");

   policies.addComponent(policy);

   return policies;  
}
```

**Now my question:**

I know in Log4j 1.X.X version it was quite easy to add an error handler to a Logger.
You could simply do this:

```
logger.setErrorHandler(your error handler);
```

How can I do this in Log4j2 version 2.13.3 with the code above?

Comment: @Coolman this is not what I need. I need the application to **shut down** in case of a failure. Not to change appenders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug. Please create a [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2) issue for it. AbstractAppender supports adding an error handler via the setErrorHandler method, however there is no ErrorHandler plugin type and AbstractAppender's Builder doesn't supply an error handler attribute to specify one. This means the only way to accomplish this is to write a customer Appender or write a wrapper for an Appender that injects the error handler in its constructor or start method.

Comment: I was able to add the `ErrorHandler` by getting the `Appenders` from the `LogContext` after i added them.

Unfortunately, even though my ErrorHandler has been added to the appenders now. The ErrorHandler is not called when an exception occured for some reason.

I locked a file to force an IOException and it was handled by the DefaultExceptionHandler.

Could it be that I don't need to add an ErrorHandler but and ExceptionHandler?

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Has the problem been reported?